# create a crash report for an Android application

Tags: android, crash-reports

I want to create a crash report for an Android application not on the Google play store. How to do it?

My application is used only for my clients so I can't published it on Google play and I need to get the crash by email or by any other way. The most important is to correct an error that happened rarely with my clients but is very important for me to correct it.

any help please from where do I have to start?? any link ?? or any easy way to do it.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 3rd party libraries like BugSense(http://bugsense.com/)
It offers crash reports with call stack and phone state and is very easy to use, one line only ! The only con is that your application needs to have internet access. If its offline then you need to have manual logs(write a log file on phone memory)that your users can forward to you.

Edit: Docs here - https://www.bugsense.com/docs/android

Comment: Thank you so much for your super fast answer. I'll try it and will reply you what will happen :))

Comment: Thank you I added +1
but my question is: what about this "Enjoy the Plus (Trial period) plan for free for 14 more days! Upgrade today and get -20% for 2 months!" do i have to subscribe after 14 days ?? Or i can continue with the free trial ?? I love it but I need something free .. And It's working great it's really very easy

Comment: I'll mark your answer as the correct answer for now, I will check after 14 days and hope that it will continue working for free. thanks a lot it's really easy :)

Comment: No its free for 500 errors and retains data for 7 days. Check https://www.bugsense.com/account#billing

Comment: thank you!! it's really very easy I only signed up, add my project and follow the small guide [https://www.bugsense.com/docs/android] exactly. for the users who have any questions I can help.
+1 for your comment too

Answer (score 0):

You can try **ACRA** tool. Its free API .

here is link:  [ACRA](http://acra.ch/).

or you can implement **UncaughtExceptionHandler** in your apps.

Implemented by objects that want to handle cases where a thread is being terminated by an uncaught exception. Upon such termination, the handler is notified of the terminating thread and causal exception. If there is no explicit handler set then the thread's group is the default handler.

[UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)

Comment: I downloaded acra-4.5.0.zip and extract it then I added acra-4.5.0-sources.jar in libs, then i right click it and add it to build path. but still cant read ACRA.init(this); while i added import org.acra.*; without any problem :( so what do I have to do ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it :https://code.google.com/p/acra/

- Just copy acra-xxx.jar into libs folder and put below code on you Application.java

  @ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", mailTo = "", customReportContent = {
      ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
      ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL,
      ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT }, mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST, resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)

  public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      ACRA.init(this);
  }
  }

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different solutions available for Android, Bugsense and Acra are two of them. Though Crittercism has a more mature solution and is one of the few that collects exceptions from NDK (or Dalvik) crashes.

Their free tier retains 30 days of data at 30k MAU (which is their pricing method, not the number of exceptions).

Here's a link: http://www.crittercism.com

Their docs: https://app.crittercism.com/developers/docs-android

As a note, the NDK monitoring is available for their paid tier (Professional).

Comment: thank you for you answer.. I already used Bugsense and it really helped me for what I need for now.. I will use NDK surely I'll add Crittercism.. and hope your answer will help the others :)